# Installation problem!

Tags: installation, windows, oracle

I am trying to install Ubuntu onto Oracle VM VirtualBox which I'm running on a windows vista laptop. I have gotten to the point of 'who are you?' Then once I hit 'continue' and wait for the bar to loaf it gets all the way to the end and then nothing.. There is a white round load symbol that I think was the mouse pointer but when I even put my mouse over the screen it doesn't come on the screen unless I'm pointing at the frame of the page so the scroll bar and menu options. This is the second time I'm trying this and it is stuck at the same spot again. What can I do about this? And why is it happening please thank you in advance for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you give the VM at least 1GB of RAM. RAM is known to crash the UI installer.

[image]